# Error en la linea 32, no toma ecuación

Tags: java

Ayuda en la linea 32, no toma ecuación

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package ejercicio5Sueldo;
//Desarrrollo del ejercicio 5
/*Curso:Martes y Viernes
Alumno: */
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 *
 * @author Tan3Dey
 */
public class Ejercicio5Sueldo {
    public static void main (String args[]) 
    {
        float monto, venta1, venta2, venta3, ventas, sueldo;

        Scanner teclado = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Ingrese monto en pesos($): ");
        monto = teclado.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Ingrese venta 1: ");
        venta1 = teclado.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Ingrese venta 2: ");
        venta2 = teclado.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Ingrese venta 3: ");
        venta3 = teclado.nextInt();

        ventas = venta1+venta2+venta3;        
        sueldo = monto + (0,10*ventas);

        System.out.println(" Tu sueldo es de $ " + sueldo);

    }
}
```

Comment: Te invito a que reformules tu pregunta. Te ayudará a obtener respuestas indicar qué intentas hacer, qué probaste y qué resultados obtuviste. Saludos!

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Whor!, es importante realices el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y además obtienes tu primera medalla. Además es **muy importante revisar [ask]** que te brinda información para realizar una buena pregunta, esta sea bien recibida en la comunidad y de esta forma obtengas buenas respuestas, saludos y suerte!.

Comment: Hola gracias, espero haber cumplido con las normas.

Comment: Ya estuve viendo la conversion de variables gracias a todos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La linea 32 indica

```
sueldo = monto + (0,10*ventas);
```

El problema aquí es que **no puedes definir un número con punto flotante usando ","**, debes usar ".", además agrega la f al final para indicar que el valor es del tipo `float`.

```
sueldo = monto + (0.10f * ventas);
```

También puedes realizar un casting para convertir la operación pero es indispensable usar ".":

```
 sueldo =  monto + (float)(0.10 * ventas);
```

---

Clase corregida:

```
public class Ejercicio5Sueldo {
    public static void main (String args[]) 
    {
        float monto, venta1, venta2, venta3, ventas, sueldo;

        Scanner teclado = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Ingrese monto en pesos($): ");
        monto = teclado.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Ingrese venta 1: ");
        venta1 = teclado.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Ingrese venta 2: ");
        venta2 = teclado.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Ingrese venta 3: ");
        venta3 = teclado.nextInt();

        ventas = venta1+venta2+venta3;        
        sueldo = monto + (0.10f * ventas);

        System.out.println(" Tu sueldo es de $ " + sueldo);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solo hay que hacer un **Cast** a **float** y usar punto en lugar de coma:

```
public class Ejercicio5Sueldo {
    public static void main (String args[]) 
    {
        float monto, venta1, venta2, venta3,  sueldo;
        float ventas;

        Scanner teclado = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Ingrese monto en pesos($): ");
        monto = teclado.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Ingrese venta 1: ");
        venta1 = teclado.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Ingrese venta 2: ");
        venta2 = teclado.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Ingrese venta 3: ");
        venta3 = teclado.nextInt();

        ventas = venta1+venta2+venta3;    
        System.out.println("Ventas " + ventas);
        sueldo = (float) (monto + 0.10*ventas);

        System.out.println(" Tu sueldo es de $ " + sueldo);

    }
}
```

**sueldo = (float) (monto + 0.10*ventas);**

Answer (score -1):

intenta cambiar la coma por un punto

```
sueldo = monto + (0.10*ventas);
```

Comment: Seguiría teniendo el mismo problema si no le indica el tipo